# Получение координат слова в TextNode

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется `TextNode`:

```
<div>aaa bbb ccc</div>
```

(точнее элемент, содержащий ровно одну `TextNode`)

Я могу получить координаты всего текста вот так:

```js
let element = document.querySelector('div');
let node = element.childNodes[0];
let range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(node);
let rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(rect);
```

```html
<div>aaa bbb ccc</div>
```

Как я могу получить координаты только слова `bbb` (я знаю индексы его начала и конца в соответствующей `TextNode`)? Под координатами имеются в виду четыре числа `left`, `top`, `height` и `width`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать методы [`Range.setStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Range/setStart) и [`Range.setEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Range/setEnd):

```js
let element = document.querySelector('div');
let node = element.childNodes[0];
let range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(node, 4);
range.setEnd(node, 7);
let rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(rect);
```

```html
<div>aaa bbb ccc</div>
```

А кто-то не смог правильно найти координаты слова `bbb`, поэтому и задал этот вопрос :(